# Javascript is disabled in your browser when logging with google through selenium

Tags: selenium, oauth-2.0, gmail, mozilla

I'm trying to login through gmail(Oauth2) with selenium test but all the time I'm getting the same error

> You've reached this page because we have detected that JavaScript is disabled in your browser.The page you attempted to load cannot display properly if scripts are disabled.
>   Please enable scripts and retry the operation or go back in your browser.

The JavaScript is enabled in Mozzila but i'm still getting this error. Is there any propertie that need to be set in selenium or is it problem in login with Oauth2?

Comment: Have you tried another browser? Are cookies enabled? (Random things that I would check were I suffering from the problem.)

Comment: No, my current implementation is with mozilla web driver, but as much as i found, the problem may be in oauth2 because a lot of people are getting this error also in android apps when using oaut2 to login with gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Selenium web driver event. Instead of just driver.click the allow button after Oauthredirection I was calling driver.submit, so gmail was blocking this as security issue and redirect to no script found URL.